# read file in a folder via python in mac

Tags: python, macos, filesystems

I want to read file for find md5 of file and copy file in mac.
However, I get no such file or directory error. My codes are as follows;

```
import os
import hashlib

def md5bul (dosyayolu):
    try:
        BLOCKSIZE = 65536
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open(dosyayolu, 'rb' 'utf8') as afile:
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        print(hasher.hexdigest())
    except IOError, e:
        print  ' Error %s' %e 


root = '/Users/username/'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        dosya = path+name
        md5bul (path,name)
        print os.path.join(path, name)
```

but, I get following error message ;

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I don't understant why I get this error message

did you realize errors in codes ?

Answer (score 0):

well quite obvious that `dosya = path+name` is incorrect as `path` from `os.walk` doesn't have a trailing slash, like: **/Users/username**, so adding filename 'test' becomes **Users/usernametest** which is incorrect.

Secondly, your `md5bul (dosyayolu)` is taking one argument where you are call with 2 `md5bul (path,name)`, and that's why it throws *file not found* error.

You may change to calling:

```
mdfbul(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

but;

```
print dosya = path + name
```

output as "/Users/username/Desktop/C"

and secondly yes you are true but I wrong paste code.
normally, I write this line as md5bul (dosyayolu)

Answer (score 0):

ok @anzel I solve this issue thanks.
I change my code as follows;

```
with open(os.path.join (path,name), 'rb' 'utf8') as afile:
```